# Sencha Touch: dynamic button background

Tags: button, touch, extjs, dataview

We're using a DataView to display a series of buttons. The data comes from a store and each model in it contains the background color for a button. I can change the button's text but how can I change the background color based on the value from the model?

This is the ButtonData model:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.model.ButtonData', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
         {name: 'text', type: 'auto'},
         {name: 'color', type: 'auto'}
           ]
       }
});
```

Based on this example http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2
I have a DataItem with this config:

```
config : {  
      dataMap: {  
          getButton : { setText: 'text'}, // works!

 //problem is here: how do I set the background color based on the 'color' 
 // member form the 'ButtonData' model? 
                 },

    button: { 
      ui: 'plain' 
        }
```

}

So the problem is how to set the background color based on the 'color' member form the 'ButtonData' model?

Thx,

Maarten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
config : {  
  dataMap: {  
      getButton : { 
         setText: 'text',
         setButton: {}
      }
  }
}
```

Then implement the setButton function in your component used in the dataview. You can also want to consider to have a single function there and do all the job in that.

Comment: Eventually we used a similar approach: we derived a class from Button and added a setColor function to it to change the color. Thx for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have not a color property in the button widget because the color of the button is an composed effect including desaturate, darking, gradients... So you can not simply change the color on only one place.

The recomended option would be create your own theme (starting from the standard theme) and then create different theme UI for buttons. This can be done adding lines like this in your theme:

```
// you can add as many as you want.
@include sencha-button-ui('color1', #FF0000, 'glossy');
@include sencha-button-ui('color2', #00FF00, 'glossy');
```

See more options in the themes/stylesheets/sencha-touch/default/widgets/_buttons.scss file of sencha-touch theme.

Then you can change the ui property on your buttons acording to your model. This link could be helpful to get your own theme up and running:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/getting-sassy-with-css

Other advantages of work with your own theme is that is more easy touch the css, you can optimize the size of your css file removing parts you don't needing, etc.